# NSXMLParser values not being retained

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser

This is similar to my previous question. I didn't get an answer, maybe by changing the question I might get an answer.

Here is my parsing code:

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser  didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName  
                                          namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI  
                                         qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName   
                                            attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict 
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kimgurl]
        || [elementName isEqualToString:kone_x]
        || [elementName isEqualToString:kone_y]
        || [elementName isEqualToString:kone_radius]
        || [elementName isEqualToString:ktwo_x]
        || [elementName isEqualToString:ktwo_y]
        || [elementName isEqualToString:ktwo_radius]) 
    {
        elementFound = YES;
        theItems = [[Items alloc] init];
    }
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
                                      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
                                     qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{   
    if([elementName isEqualToString:kimgurl])
    {
        theItems.imageURL = self.currentValue;
        [self.currentValue setString:@""];
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:kone_x])
    {
        theItems.iOne_X = self.currentValue;
        [self.currentValue setString:@""];
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:kone_y])
    {
        theItems.iOne_Y = self.currentValue;
        [self.currentValue setString:@""];
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:kone_radius])
    {
        theItems.iOne_Radius = self.currentValue;
        [self.currentValue setString:@""];
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:ktwo_x])
    {
        theItems.iTwo_X = self.currentValue;
        [self.currentValue setString:@""];
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:ktwo_y])
    {
        theItems.iTwo_Y = self.currentValue;
        [self.currentValue setString:@""];
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:ktwo_radius])
    {
        theItems.iTwo_Radius = self.currentValue;
        [self.currentValue setString:@""];
    }

}

-(void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
{   
    NSLog(@"enddocument: %@", theItems.imageURL);
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{
    if (elementFound == YES) {
        if(!currentValue)
        {
            currentValue = [NSMutableString string];
        }

        [currentValue appendString: string];
    }
}
```

When I get to parserDidEndDocument. The theItems class is empty.

Here is Items.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


 @interface Items : NSObject {
     @private
     //parsed data
     NSString *imageURL;
     NSString *iOne_X;
     NSString *iOne_Y;
     NSString *iOne_Radius;
     NSString *iTwo_X;
     NSString *iTwo_Y;
     NSString *iTwo_Radius;
 }

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imageURL;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *iOne_X;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *iOne_Y;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *iOne_Radius;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *iTwo_X;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *iTwo_Y;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *iTwo_Radius;


@end
```

here is Items.m

```
#import "Items.h"


@implementation Items
@synthesize imageURL;
@synthesize iOne_X;
@synthesize iOne_Y;
@synthesize iOne_Radius;
@synthesize iTwo_X;
@synthesize iTwo_Y;
@synthesize iTwo_Radius;

-(void)dealloc
{
    [imageURL release];
    [iOne_X release];
    [iOne_Y release];
    [iOne_Radius release];
    [iTwo_X release];
    [iTwo_Y release];
    [iTwo_Radius release];  
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

here is my RootViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Items;

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    NSMutableData *downloadData;
    NSURLConnection *connection;

    BOOL elementFound;
    NSMutableString *currentValue;
    NSMutableDictionary *pictures;

    //---xml parsing---
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser;

    Items *theItems;
    NSMutableArray *aItems;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Items *theItems;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *aItems;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *currentValue;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *downloadData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection *connection;

@end
```

xml file example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <test>
        <url>url</url>
        <one_x>83</one_x>
        <one_y>187</one_y>
        <one_radius>80</one_radius>
        <two_x>183</two_x>
        <two_y>193</two_y>
        <two_radius>76</two_radius>
    </test>
</data>
```

Comment: You would increase your chances of getting an answer a lot by formatting your code properly and reducing it to the relevant parts, if possible. This is very hard to read.

Comment: It looks like a new theItems is created every time an element is started, replacing the old one but without keeping the old one.  So basically, you have a huge memory leak, and when you're done, theItems is pointing to the very last parsed element's data.  I'm guessing that's not what you intended.

Comment: I tried to format the code in the blocks, but to me, seems rather difficult. Anyways, even if I create the theItems in the viewDidLoad I get the same results.

Comment: Try accessing theItems as a property - use `self.theItems` instead of `theItems`

Comment: I tried that. `parseDidEndDocument` is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple of potential problems. In your didStartElement method you are alloc/init'ing a new Items object for every element and overwriting your previous one. Perhaps you can move the Items init into your –parserDidStartDocument: method. When you init, it should also look more like this:

Items *items = [[Items alloc] init];
self.theItems = items;
[items release];

Then you'll have the correct retain count when you are done.

I'd also recommend changing your NSString @property declarations to be copy instead of retain. The code:

```
theItems.imageURL = self.currentValue;
[self.currentValue setString:@""];
```

... isn't doing what you think. theItems.imageURL is going to be pointing at your NSMutableString and then you clear the mutable string right after which means imageURL is pointing at an empty mutable string. Then after all of the other iterations, all of them are pointing at the same NSMutableString which is empty. If you change the @property declarations to copy, then it'll set imageURL to an immutable NSString copy of the contents of self.currentValue.

Comment: Thank you. This got me one step closer. At least I know what I was doing wrong. Thank you again.